# Randomly access to rowset/resultset with PDO Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowset

I want to access randomly to a result sets retuned from a Stored Procedure using PDO Mysql and PHP. I found [PDOStatement::nextRowset](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) but the access to the result sets seems to be sequential.

**EDIT**
I'm looking for some like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;port=$port;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
$statement  = "CALL FooSP()";
$query = $pdo->prepare($statement);
$query->execute();

$query->resultSet[1][0]["ColumnFoo"] // Second Resultset, first row, column "ColumnFoo"
$query->resultSet[3][1]["ColumnBar"] // third Resultset, second row, columna "ColumnBar"
$query->resultSet[0][0]["Column1"] // first Resultset, first row, columna "Column1"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why don't you just order your query randomly? Ex. `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: `$query->resultSet[rand(0, $query->rowCount()];`

Comment: Yeah you'll want to edit FooSP's declaration to return random results on each call. Other methods would be inefficient as it would mean loading data that you are not using.

Comment: No, I need all result sets.

Answer (score 0):

If You need all resultsets - just prefetch them using [next rowset](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) like this:

```
<?php
$sql = 'CALL multiple_rowsets()';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$fetched_rowsets = array();
do {
    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if ($rowset) 
    {
        $fetched_rowsets[] = $rowset;
    }
# This is important part. 
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
#Now You got the table with all data from all resultsets, fetched in PHP memory.
$fetched_rowsets[1][0]["ColumnFoo"];
$fetched_rowsets[3][1]["ColumnBar"];
$fetched_rowsets[0][0]["Column1"];
?>
```

Just remember that it can be memory consuming.